# Redundantly load Angular module on lower level?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module, angular-ui-router

Lets say we have these two Angular modules:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router', 'mySubApp']);

angular.module('mySubApp', []);
```

And lets say mySubApp also uses ui.router directly (by injecting $stateParams into its controller). Is it then better to also load ui.router in this module?:

```
angular.module('mySubApp', ['ui.router']);
```

I know it's not necessary functionality-wise, but is it considered a good practice? I had a particularly hard time Googling this dilemma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If **myApp** is the main application module, and **mySubApp** is a submodule of the first one, ie. mySubApp will run in that specific parent module, then is not needed to have the dependency in both. You could have some core modules that are global for the entire application.

However, I would probably have that in every module that uses the dependency, because you want the modules to act as application blocks-reusable, so once you include a module, you want to have it with all it's dependencies.

Other explanations can be found in this [style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#modularity)

Answer (score 0):

I would. What if `mySubApp` get used in another parent app that doesn't include `ui.router`?

If you want to treat it like a standalone module, it should define its dependencies.